# Apache Derby startup error java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.services.timer is sealed

Tags: java, exception, derby, securityexception

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed Derby 10.12.1.1. I have followed installation instructions from Apache website.

My `CLASSPATH` has been set as

```
/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/local/hive/lib/*:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/usr/local/derby/lib/derbytools.jar
```

When I try to start Derby

```
hduser@HadoopMaster:/usr/local/derby/data$ /usr/local/derby/bin/startNetworkServer
```

I get

```
Tue Nov 10 23:50:18 AEDT 2015 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.services.timer is sealed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:399)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.definePackageInternal(URLClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getImplementations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getDefaultImplementations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.startNetworkServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.startNetworkServer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.blockingStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.executeWork(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.services.timer is sealed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:399)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.definePackageInternal(URLClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getImplementations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getDefaultImplementations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Check your CLASSPATH very carefully. Sealing violations often arise when you accidentally have multiple different versions of the Derby software at different locations within your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks so much Bryan. You are absolutely correct. The hive/lib also contains an older derby.jar that must have been causing the issue.

Comment: Which derby.jar should be removed Or What to do ?

Comment: Sorry @ashu17188 for not replying earlier. Have been a bit inactive. If I remember correctly then the lib folder inside hive installation had a couple derby jars which I had to remove. I have recently installed Hive 2 and associated Derby. Did not have any issues this time.